# Error while adding dependency for angular-materialize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

I want to use materialize for my angular project from https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize but I get the error

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module F1FeederApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   Failed to instantiate module ui.materialize due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.materialize' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

In my app.js:

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp', [
        'ui.materialize',
        'F1FeederApp.services',
        'F1FeederApp.controllers',
        'ngRoute'
        ]).
```

What am I doing wrong? According to the link above these declarations should have been enough..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this in root of your project if you are using bower.

```
bower install angular-materialize --save
```

and add the source file `angular-materialize/src/angular-materialize.js` into your `index.html`

**OR**

If you are not using bower or node download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krescruz/angular-materialize/master/src/angular-materialize.js) file in your project and add it in your index.html

Hope this helps